# Установка даты в @Html.EditorFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Не могу вывести значение нужной даты в @Html.EditorFor там всегда отображается только текущая дата, как не переписывай в атрибуте @Value есть нужная дата но отображается все равно текущая. Кошмар какой то на таком сесть.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }

    <td class="control-buttons">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateofBirth, new { @Value = Model.DateofBirth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),@class = "editorfor_date_filter", @type = "date", @id = "editorfor_date_filter" })</td>
```

**Как вывести нужную дату из переменной.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#editorfor_date_filter').val('@Model.DateofBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")');
    });
</script>
```